# putting and getting array into array php

Tags: php, arrays

```
$sellr_id=$this->model_checkout_getdistanceofseller->getdistanceofseller1($order_data);
            foreach($sellr_id as $id){

            echo'got id'.$id;


        }
        //echo"seller id array".$sellr_id[0];
        //echo"seller id array".$sellr_id[1];
    $order_data['sellr_id']=$sellr_id;
```

this is my code here i m calling a function which is returning an array and i have anther array $order_data i want to put $id's all values into this $order_data['sellr_id'] ..............if anyone know this plz help me how can i do this

Comment: look into array_merge(), I think that is what you need

Comment: i want to put all ids in $order_data['sellr_id']

Comment: update your question and add a proper data sample and the expected  result please

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$sellr_id = $this->model_checkout_getdistanceofseller->getdistanceofseller1($order_data);
$order_data['sellr_id'] = $sellr_id
```